# Regex: Put some tags at the beginning of the line, but only those that are framed in a comment html

Tags: powershell, notepad++, regex, powershell-5.0, powershell-ise

I wanna put some tags at the beginning of the line, but only those that are framed in a comment html. For example:

```
<!-- ARTICOL START -->

<p class="text_obisnuit">I want go home</p>         <p class="text_obisnuit2">Tv is my passion <em>"It is true"</em></p>         <p class="text_obisnuit">No one is here</p>  <p class="text_obisnuit2">God is my hero</p>

<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->
```

**The output should be:**

```
<!-- ARTICOL START -->

<p class="text_obisnuit">I want go home</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit2">Tv is my passion <em>"It is true"</em></p>
<p class="text_obisnuit">No one is here</p>
<p class="text_obisnuit2">God is my hero</p>

<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->
```

My regex's is not good:

**FIND:**

`(<\!-- ARTICOL START -->)(.*)(<p class="text_obisnuit2">.*?</p>)|(<p class="text_obisnuit">.*?</p>)(.*)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)`

**Replace by:** `\1\2\r\3\4\5`

**OR**

`(<\!-- ARTICOL START -->)(.*)(<p class=".*?">.*?</p>)(.*)(<\!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)`

**Replace by:** `\1\2\r\3\4\5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:.*?<!-- ARTICOL START -->|\G).*?</p>\K\h+(?=<p .*?<!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->)`
- Replace with: `\n`  OR `\r\n` depending on your platform.
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                         # non capture group
    .*?                         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    <!-- ARTICOL START -->      # literally
  |                           # OR
    \G                          # restart from last match position
)                           # end group
.*?                         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
</p>                        # closing tag
\K                          # forget all we have seen until this position
\h+                         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
(?=                         # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    <p                          # openning tag, don't forget the space just after "<p"
    .*?                         # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    <!-- ARTICOL FINAL -->      # literally
)                           # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: thanks @Toto works great

Comment: but, I still not understand what exactly does `\G` ?

Comment: @JustMe: `\G` is some kind of recursion. In this example, regex engine matches `.*?<!-- ARTICOL START -->` then anything until end tag `</p>` and some spaces `\h+`and replace them with linefeed, in the next turn `\G` says to regex engine to try to match another `</p>SPACES`, starting from the previous position. so it finds all the spaces just after `</p>` in the whole string.